# Composer update wamp windows 7

Tags: composer-php, wamp

I am trying to update my composer it showing could not input file: C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\composer.phar.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNiNs.png)

I tried stuff which I got from google

Comment: 1) Where did you install composer. 2) Is this your first attempt to use compose after installing it or has it suddenly stopped working

Comment: I installed composer form getcomposer.org. This is my first attempt after installing composer.

Comment: Then finish reading the install instructions, or check you did it correctly.